# Using content called from AJAX into another AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On the page where my form will be manipulated, I have the following AJAX calls to be performed as soon as the page is loaded. I want to have a dropdown list of Supplier and Product ID's. This AJAX call is referencing a url that connects to a database and pulls all the current ID values and throws them into a `<option>` tags under a `<select>` dropdown element.

```
$(function(){
    // this is getting the dropdown values for the Supplier ID dropdown
    $.ajax({
      url: "getSuppliers.php",
      async: true,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#supplier").html(result);
      }
    })


    // this is getting the dropdown values for the Product ID dropdown
    $.ajax({
      url: "getProducts.php",
      async: true,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#products").html(result);
      }
    })

  });
```

The next step for me is call AJAX to do something when this dropdown item changes. I have done the following to the `<select>` element in both `getSuppliers.php` and `getProducts.php` that I just referenced.

```
  <option name="supplierID" value=$row["SupplierID"] onchange="suppChange()"> $row["SupplierID"] </option>";
```

I am calling the function, `suppChange()` to be performed when this dropdown value changes. I have `suppChange()` in the main file where my form is located (the same file I have my first two AJAX calls in). `suppChange()` looks like this:

```
  function suppChange() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "displaySuppliers.php",
        async: true,
        success: function(result) {
          $("#supplierStatic").html(result);
          $("#products").html("TESTING");
        }
      })
  }
```

When I change the form, nothing happens. It has nothing to do with an invalid `<option>`, as I've tried grabbing this value with `console.log(supplierID)` and am getting the correct value. I am just wondering why the `onchange=suppChange()` is not doing anything and calling the function when I change the drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onchange should be used in the `select` tag, not in the `option` tag

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe I have been going at this for as long as I have when it was such a simple fix.

Comment: This fixed the problem then?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to click "solve" but there is a wait time. I'm sure there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, though, but I'm just learning what AJAX is and how to code with databases and webpages.

Comment: try to use newer apis if you're just getting into async calls. APIs like `fetch` are more common nowadays with promises